# Is there a way to limit networkx upstream node depth search

Tags: networkx

I'm new to NetworkX in Python. I have a directed graph and I'm using nx.edge_dfs to filter out nodes that have no upstream edges / links. It works but it's very slow. I just need to check that there are more than 3 upstream nodes. Is there a better way to do this?
(I've editted this as I initially pasted the wrong function)

Thanks

```
# if there are <x upstream nodes, return a fail code
elif len(list(nx.edge_dfs(G,dwnstr, orientation='reverse')))< 2: # 2 as a psuedo depth.
    return (1)
```

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Comment: This is what I'm using at the moment, it's a snip of one of the criteria. I'm new to stackoverflow, sorry about the formatting.

    elif len(list(nx.edge_dfs(G,dwnstr, orientation='reverse')))<4: # I've used 4 as a psuedo depth.
        print ('fail-'+str(dwnstr)+'  '+str(len(list(nx.edge_dfs(G,dwnstr, orientation='reverse'))))+' has no_upstream')
        return (1)

Comment: Can you post the code as an edit in your original post? It is hard to read unformatted code.